# Number of Integers

Tags: python

Write a function that receives a string as input and returns the number of integer numbers present in every token from the string. Example:

Input: potato 123 potato potata 1 23423p 12/4 test

Output: 2

This is the code that I have tried, but it doesn't work

```
import re
text = input("Enter a sentence both string and intenger: ")
print("The original sting: " + text)
temp = re.findall(r'\d+', text)
res = list(map(int, temp))
print("The numbers list is: " + str(res))
```

Comment: why would the output be 2? what does "doesnt work" mean?

Comment: that there are 2 words that are ints like 123 and 1

Comment: 12/4 is not an integer - its a calculation

Comment: yeah my bad I did not see the lone 1

Comment: You can simply add spaces before and after like ```re.findall(r' \d+ ', a)```, which gives the resulst as ```[' 123 ', ' 1 ']```. Then you may map it to int.

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the string on every space character and use a list comprehension to get only the strings that represent integers (using `str.isdigit`):

```
text = input("Enter a sentence both string and integer: ")

res = [int(s) for s in text.split() if s.isdigit()]

print("The numbers list is:", res)
print("The number of integer is :", len(res))
```

Input:

```
potato 123 potato potata 1 23423p 12/4 test
```

Output:

```
The numbers list is: [123, 1]
The number of integers is: 2
```

Comment: This solution does not work if I do with txt file (big file). I change the text = input("Enter a sentence both string and integer: ") to text = open("SMSSpamCollection.txt", "r")

Answer (score 0):

Just add \s at the beginning and end of your regex pattern:

```
import re
text = input("Enter a sentence both string and intenger: ")
print("The original sting: " + text)
temp = re.findall(r'\s\d+\s', text)
res = list(map(int, temp))
print("The numbers list is: " + str(res))
```

Comment: This solution does not work if I do with txt file (big file). I change the text = input("Enter a sentence both string and integer: ") to text = open("SMSSpamCollection.txt", "r")